# execute the python program on a webpage and display output

Tags: php, python, ssh, raspberry-pi, lamp

I have 5 python programs in my raspberry pi. I have installed LAMP Server in raspberry pi.

Now I would like to make a web page and execute those program.

Is there any way to execute them and display the output on the web browser?

Comment: Yup, you can look into using [webpy](http://webpy.org/install) to serve up input from your python files on a HTTP server then access that using a web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute like so:

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/custom/test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```

There is further information [Running a python script from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php)

You can then make a simple page with buttons that executes the relevant scripts.