# PHP call Python script and the python script cannot write to a file

Tags: php, python

I have a PHP script which calls a python script.
The Python script does a simple write to file function.

Python:

```
f = open("xxx", "w")
f.write("xxxxxx")
f.close
```

PHP:

```
$output = system("python /home/xxxx/training/scripts/load.py);
echo $output;
```

If I run the Python directly, it is able to create and write to the file.
But when I use the PHP to call it, no file will be created and written.
Is that because of some system path related issue?
How to fix it?

p.s. If I run a "whoami", it shows the user as "apache". Is that the possible reason that the write-to-file failed?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Is your file path relative or fully specified? Could be a working directory issue.

Comment: Could be anything. Where's the php side? If you want answers, provide everything.

Comment: If by "use PHP" you mean calling it via browser, maybe the user that runs the webserver (in debian-based it would be wwwdata, in redhat-like httpd, I think) doesn't have write permission in the target dir.

Comment: Hi I am using absolute path, not relative.

Comment: Yes, what i meant by "use PHP" is calling it via browser. But that directory is in 777

Comment: PHP side actually nothing special $output = system("/usr/bin/python /home/xxx/training/scripts/load.py Practice 001 002 003");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this python script will have no output and the php code won't save command's output to the variable `output` instead it will print it immediately, you should use shell_exec for that

E.g.

```
<?php 
$output = shell_exec("python script.py");
print $output;
?>
```

anyways,

> Tested on Ubuntu Server 10.04. I hope it helps you also on Archlinux.
>
> In PHP:
>
> ```
> <?php 
>
> $command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/custom/test.py');
> $output = shell_exec($command);
> echo $output;
>
> ?>
> ```
>
> In Python file 'test.py' verify this text in first line: (see shebang
>   explain):
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env python
> ```
>
> Also Python file should have correct privileges (execution for user
>   www-data / apache if Php script runs in browser or through curl)
>   and/or must be "executable". Also all commands in .py file must have
>   correct privileges.
>
> ```
> chmod +x myscript.py
> ```

Source: [Running a Python script from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php)

Comment: Hi Abdallah, sorry I was my typo here. What I did in my script is f = open("xxx", "w")

Comment: Hi @Abdallah, I have updated the question with code.