# Running python script from php and write to a file

Tags: php, python

My php code is in htdocs/series/index.php.
My python code location is /home/shivam/Desktop/hello.py
I am running php using xampp in ubuntu.
here is php code

```
 <?php
$command = escapeshellcmd('/home/shivam/Desktop/hello.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

here is my python code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
with open("/home/shivam/Desktop/solution.txt", "w") as myfile:
    myfile.write("write text")
```

I am trying to run the python script using php to write to a file 'solution.txt'. When i write something myself to solution.txt and open it in read mode using python script via php then it works but when i try to write using above code ,i am unable to do so. 
One more thing, none of the code below the line "with open("/home/shivam/Desktop/solution.txt", "w") as myfile:" gets executed.
I have tried the solution given in : [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547008/php-call-python-script-and-the-python-script-cannot-write-to-a-file)

Comment: Did you also change the permissions as suggested in the link?

Comment: i did  chmod +x hello.py

Comment: You original code has valid php tags, right? It says ` ?php`, not `<?php` here.

Comment: what else permission do i need to give to python and php file.

Answer (score 2):

Absolute paths to executables and files...

**run_py.php**

```
<?php
$command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/bin/python /home/user/some_py.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

**some_py.py**

```
with open("/home/user/solution.txt", "w") as myfile:
    myfile.write("write text")
```

Output:

```
user@box:~/$ php run_py.php 
user@box:~/$ cat solution.txt 
write text
```

Comment: i know this code is working. But I have to run it on browser.

Comment: @shivam12393 *"i know this code is working."* Did you actually try running it? Enable PHP error reporting and check if maybe your PHP/server user (www-data?) isn't allowed to write the file. PHP may not be allowed to open a shell.

Comment: @shivam12393 It would help if you added your debugging input and output to the question. E.g. "I tried adding [code] to the script and got this output: [browser/terminal output]"