# Running Python script in PHP: capture all outputs

Tags: php, python

I have a `Python` program that has multiple `print` statements in it. When I execute the program from `PHP`, the output displayed is just the value printed by the last `print` statement. Is there a way to capture values printed by all the `print` statements in the `Python` script?

`PHP` code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$output = exec("python script.py");
echo $output;
?>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try with `shell_exec` - Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string

> escapeshellcmd() escapes any characters in a string that might be used
>   to trick a shell command into executing arbitrary commands.

Name your file like- `python_script.py` and follow the given script-

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('python_script.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```

Ref# [running-a-python-script-from-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php)