# running python script from php giving me null output

Tags: php, python

i want to open and execute a python file using php . for this reason i’m using xamp . my php and python both files resides in htdocs folder. here is the code.

```
$output = shell_exec("python untitled6.py");
var_dump($output);
```

i have also tried different methods like

```
$python = 'C:\\Users\\Imama\\Anaconda2\\python.exe' ;
$pyscript= 'E:\\xamp\\htdocs\\untitled6.py' ;
$cmd = "$python $pyscript";
echo $cmd;
$result= exec($cmd);
```

i want help regarding plx :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Python script in PHP: capture all outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37042904/running-python-script-in-php-capture-all-outputs)

Comment: Do you get any errors? Can you actually use `shell_exec()`? Check this out to find out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581560/php-how-to-know-if-server-allows-shell-exec

Comment: no i don't get errors

Comment: same issue from my side