# Run python script on PHP

Tags: php

I'm new in PHP and I'm looking for the way to run my Python script via PHP. I'm now using Filezilla to edit my index page.
I don't know if it's possible to run a python script on PHP but I saw some posts on google about it and I thought to try. I need to convert in anyway the line where I must type the channel into a php input and to run the script with a simple button.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php

Comment: This is not what I need.