# PHP exec not executing python script with module imports

Tags: raspberry-pi

OK so im trying to get `exec()` to execute a script that works fine from idle.

If I try a simple script it works fine, such as:

```
hello = "hello"
world = "world"
print hello + " " + world
```

But the script I actually want to run wont work and I can only assume its because of the module import, the code is as follows:

```
import serial
port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', baudrate=19200, bytesize=8, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=1, timeout=5)
port.open

port.write("\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02")
```

My PHP code is:

```
 <?php

   $result = exec('python python.py');#This works fine

   echo $result

   ?>

   <?php

   $result1 = exec('python proOn.py');# This wont work

   echo $result1

   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 

$command = escapeshellcmd('proOn.py');
$result1 = shell_exec($command);
echo $result1;

?>
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php).

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately, tried everything in that link as well