# execute a python code from php and take the return value back to the php code example

Tags: php, python

I have a python script and a PHP script what I need is execute the python script through PHP and should get the return value of python code back to PHP.Here is my codes

```
<?php
$result1= passthru("python E:\naive-bayes-classifier-master\naiveBayesClassifier\return.py");

echo "return value is: $result1" . "\n";

 ?>
```

I execute this through another php script using a submit button

and here is the python code

```
def add(a, b):
   # print "ADDING %d + %d" % (a, b)
    return a + b

def subtract(a, b):
   #print "SUBTRACTING %d - %d" % (a, b)
    return a - b

def multiply(a, b):
    #print "MULTIPLYING %d * %d" % (a, b)
    return a * b

def divide(a, b):
   # print "DIVIDING %d / %d" % (a, b)
    return a / b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    divide(10,2)
```

the result I am getting is

return value is:

there no any value.Please help.Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a Python script from PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer for this problem.In python code I only return the value.But It should be printed too.So here is the modified python code.Hope this will be useful to all of you.

```
def add(a, b):
   # print "ADDING %d + %d" % (a, b)
    return a + b

def subtract(a, b):
   #print "SUBTRACTING %d - %d" % (a, b)
    return a - b

def multiply(a, b):
    #print "MULTIPLYING %d * %d" % (a, b)
    return a * b

def divide(a, b):
   # print "DIVIDING %d / %d" % (a, b)
    return a / b

if __name__ == '__main__':

   ret= divide(10,2)
   print("ret:",ret)
```