# How to execute a script from PHP

Tags: php, python

I have a PHP script that should run a Python script, what i try. Nothing seems to work. 
I gived the script and the PHP script full permission (777).
The way that i use to execute my Python script in php is:

```
    <?php 


    shell_exec('python /var/www/html/send.py');
    system('python /var/www/html/send.py');

    ?>
```

I tried a couple of methodes that are in the code above, but nothing seems to solve the issue. The strange thing is that the command is working fine when i execute it in Putty. So i don't know what could be the problem. The permissions must be right.

I found a few ways on Stack Overflow, but nothing has the same issue as me.
This is the code that should be executed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys                              #import sys
import serial                           #import Serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyS0")      #Open onze poort
ser.baudrate = 9600                     #Baudrate instellen

adres = 2
data = 1

print adres                             #Debug Info
print data                              #Debug Info

byte = chr(int(adres))                  # Omzetten adres naar Byte
ser.write(byte)                         # Uitsturen van adres over Serieeel
time.sleep(0.5)                         # Wachten (Atmel kan sloom zijn)
byte2 = chr(int(data))                  # Omzetten data naar Byte
ser.write(byte2)                        # Uitsturen van data over Serieeel

ser.close()                             # Seriele poort sluiten
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a Python script from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php)

Comment: How do you know its not working? What should the script do?

Comment: The script should send serial data from its UART. But this works fine trough Putty. So i know that something is wrong with the PHP part.

Comment: Its not a duplicate, because i tried that part. But seems not to work...

Comment: Send the data where?

Comment: I uploaded the script.

Comment: is the program Python in the default search path? Could you try using the full path to python?

Comment: I guess this the full path. /var/www/html/send.py

Comment: I meant the path to python: for me it is at `/usr/bin/python`
. You can find it `which python`

Comment: /usr/bin/python. I changed it in the Pyton script, but seems not to change anything..

Comment: permission issues?

Comment: @AlexanderMP Maybe, i gived full permission for whole /html folder... But no change.

Comment: modify the command line

`python /path/to/script > out.txt 2> error.log` Then check what's in out.txt and error.log

Comment: Does the user that runs the web server have permissions to write to the serial port device?

Comment: I got a message from the error log that the permission was denied. [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyS0'
So i guess that the user that runs the server don't have the permission... How do i give this to it?

Comment: do a `ls -al /dev` and look for the user and group who has access. Second one is the group. Now you must add the user that runs the web server to the group who has access to the device.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have enabled exec in php.ini and just put into php code this

```
<?php 
exec('python /var/www/html/send.py');
```

I think, you should run python from php's tree.
For example:

```
php script
/var/www/run.php

python script:
/var/www/python/send.py
```

after that everything should be ok

Comment: Maybe you have problem with permissions of php-fpm user?