# How to run python file from PHP file?

Tags: php, python

I have python script which I wan to load in my html via .php so, i have added this code in my test.php.

```
<?php
$command = escapeshellcmd("/var/www/html/ledon.py");
$output =  shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

Shell_exec function works as if I put ls -l instead of $command it display all files. So I am not sure what I am doing wrong with escapeshellcmd function.
Thanks.

Comment: does the script include a #! to tell it where to find python. If  not you probably want to say "python /var/www/html/ledon.py". you might also want to make sure that the user that is running your webserver is able to access that file.

Comment: I have updated my code with as you suggested python /var/www/html/ledon.py but it still gives me nothing.

Comment: what happens if you type the command at a command prompt. Then what happens if you use su to become the user running apache and run it again?

Comment: If i try to run the script from terminal with this command python ledon.py it works fine no issues there. But when i try to load it via .php it's not loading

Comment: Possible duplicate of :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a Python script from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php)

Answer (score 0):

With Python you have to invoke the interpreter by calling a script with 'python somescript.py'. Keeping in mind that I have very little knowledge of PHP, I would assume that you would need to do: `$command = escapeshellcmd("python /var/www/html/ledon.py");` assuming that your shell has a link to wherever Python is installed.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted you, there's no problem with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the official [doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#37971)

Just a quick reminder for those trying to use shell_exec on a unix-type platform and can't seem to get it to work. PHP executes as the web user on the system (`generally www for Apache`), so you need to make sure that the web user has rights to whatever files or directories that you are trying to use in the `shell_exec` command. Other wise, it won't appear to be doing anything.

Python file should have correct privileges (execution for user `www-data / apache` if PHP script runs in browser or through `curl`) and/or must be "executable". Also all commands in `.py` file must have correct privileges.

You might want to use sudo and add an exception to your script to the `sudoers` file

Answer (score 0):

Your shell command is wrong. You need to specify which program to run on the file - i.e. to run it with Python, you need to run it with Python like so:

```
python /var/www/html/ledon.py
```

However, you **also** need to use `system` rather than `shell_exec`.

Thus, your full PHP code should be:

```
<?php
$command = escapeshellcmd("python /var/www/html/ledon.py");
$output =  system($command);
echo $output;
?>
```