# Php code not running command in terminal

Tags: php, python, terminal, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

So I have been trying to turn on some lights using this code `exec("python /var/www/html/scripts/lights/lampon.py");`. When I run it directly in the terminal it works, but when I try to run this through my page, it dosen't do anything. Even when I run the code above through `php -a` it works... So I do not know what the problem is. If anyone has an answer to this it would be great. I've tried almost everything but nothing works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at SELinux? If not in production, try setting it to permissive to see if that resolves the issue. It sounds like it could be an SELinux problem.

Comment: permission issues

Comment: Another thing is that you might make the path to python absolute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a Python script from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php)