# How do I embed sklearn code in my PHP backend code?

Tags: php, python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am creating a website which uses PHP on its back end. Now I am adding machine learning capabilities to my website which are accessed by HTTP methods GET and POST. But since sklearn is in Python, how do I enable my PHP code to call python based sklearn code? Or is there a way I can use some library to call Python code?

Comment: What have you considered?

Comment: @Maor Veitsman I am a beginner in this aspect. So, I am looking for starting directions.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Running a Python script from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php)

Comment: Sameer Mahajan is right, you can use the [sklearn-porter](https://github.com/nok/sklearn-porter/), e.g. a [decision tree in PHP](https://github.com/nok/sklearn-porter/blob/master/examples/estimator/classifier/DecisionTreeClassifier/php/basics.ipynb).

Answer (score 1):

One possible option for you to consider is: https://github.com/nok/sklearn-porter

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve your goal, without calling `python` code *directly* (embedding it) from `PHP` code.

For example, let's suppose you have a web application, which is built using `PHP`, and your application contains **Articles**, and you want to add the feature of *categorizing* (tagging/classification) of those articles into some categories: News, Sport, Medical, Science, etc ...

let's say that you have built a machine learning model using `sklearn` (possibly naive Bayes model), which predicts the probability of each category. and you want to use this model within your application.

Now, you can export this model as an `API`, and make other applications use it, in our case, your web application will send the `Article` to this `API`, and get a list of predictions for each category.

For building `API` in `python` you can use: [Flask-RESTful](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), or [Django REST](https://www.django-rest-framework.org)

While this approach has some *disadvantages*, I think it's much better to design your application(s) with **modularity** in mind, keeping each service (functionality) separate from the other, makes your system more **loosely coupled**.