# Can I run a python file on Drupal?

Tags: python-3.x, drupal

Ive had Drupal for quite a while and have only recently began to use it, I know how to insert new blocks and are familiar with the system. I know basic python programming and have created a WebScraping module that I want to input into the Drupal site, Ive researched for a while now but have no idea where to even start?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php