# Web application cannot control Raspberry Pi exec python script to open camera

Tags: php, python, apache, raspberry-pi3

I build a web application and want to use PHP to exec the Python script on the Raspberry Pi. It works, but when I try to open some Python script which includes the OpenCV, nothing happens and there is no error message. I try to run this PHP in the terminal, it works fine, so I don't know what happens?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)                                       
print("VideoCapture is opened?", cap.isOpened())
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()                                      
    center = (frame.shape[1]//2, frame.shape[0]//2)              

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)               
    cv2.circle(gray, center=center, radius=100, color=(0,0,255))
    cv2.imshow("frame", gray)                                    

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()            
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a Python script from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php)

Comment: I can use php exec the python script, only not work which the python script include the opencv. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`import cv2 cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`
is not valid syntax 
I do not know if it is the same in your script but you would have to do this instead

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Comment: I post a sample opencv python script, I can run this at local, but can't use web to open this.

Comment: Thx！I fix the problem, just change the usb camera to Picamera. +_+~

Comment: What if someone needs to use USB camera did you found the solution to that @yeyou ?