# Run a python code and returning the results when clicking on a button in html/php

Tags: php, python, html, python-3.x

I already looked over almost everything online to find something that answers my question but couldn't find a solution.

So Basically what I'm trying to do is to create a website that runs python codes on button click and return the result.

I've created a very simple and basic php page test.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title> test </title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" name="runscript" value=" Run Python code " onClick="<?
php exec('python myscript.py'); ?>">
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my python code myscript.py:

```
print("Hello, world!")
```

what I want is to take back the result of the code and put it back in the website.

But I have no idea how to deal with it or how to do it.

And on the actual website that I will be building, will have to bring back graphs and plots from the python codes and I don't know either how to do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19736494/5442132

Comment: @miqdadamirali Thank you for the help, it Worked!! But do you have any idea how i can show the graphs?