# Can't run my python script with php command

Tags: php, python

I'm a php learning beginner and I'm trying to run a python file with php command. I read [Running a Python script from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php) and I did everything from the answers. But it didn't work for me.

Below is my php codes:

```
<?php 

$command = escapeshellcmd('test1.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;

?>
```

Below is my Python codes(I use Python 3.6):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

f = open("test.txt", "a+")
f.write("hiya buddy!!\n")
f.close()
print("some output")
```

I did command `chmod +x test1.py` already.
However, my test1.py didn't response anything.

Could someone help me with this problem?
Any response will be appreciated!

Comment: Did you check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49074562/9269314) ?

Comment: @bru02 yes. This is the same one I mentioned