# Running python3 from PHP via Apache on MacOS

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, macos, apache

I'm trying to execute a Python script via PHP. I can run Python 2.7 but when I call "which python" in the respective directory I only receive the absolute path for Python 2.7.

When I call the PHP script now, the output is blank - nothing happens.

I've been looking around online for the past few days and the main idea that I took away was that the script wasn't executable within a PHP/Apache context.

But trying to change the group id of the file has been a bit more complicated.

When I call:

```
chgrp _www /Users/[username]/googleSpeechApi/args_test.py
```

I receive:

```
chgrp: you are not a member of group _www
```

So I opened `vim /etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and found:

```
User _www
Group _www
```

Doesn't this tell me the user/group that an Apache user will be `_www`? Is this an issue of me calling `chgrp` in a non-sudo mode?

At the end of the day - I just want to be able to execute a python3 script (I need to use NLTK and a series of Google libraries that are only executable with Python 3) from a PHP file. If there's another way to achieving this then I'm all ears,

Cheers :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a Python script from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php)

Comment: I already checked that and the answer uses Ubuntu Server 10.04. There's different conventions for MacOS that make a lot of solutions for Ubuntu/Linux-distributed OSs' generally separate.