# Passing values from php script to python script

Tags: php, python

I am trying to execute python script from PHP.

```
<?php
$asd = "Mashwani";
$command = "test.py  $asd";
$output = passthru($command);
?>
```

In python:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

This shows me just first argument i.e ['C:\xampp\htdocs\test.py']
but sencond atgument isn't shown. 
I also tried exec(), shell_exec() instead of passthru()

Comment: they are a response here :) [Running a Python Script From PHP (Stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php)

Comment: yeah trick is to use absolute path and escapeshellcmd. only difference here is Muneeb is using windows server I think.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. i was missing path to python.