# How to run a python script in a php file?

Tags: php, python

I have node js file that is running a python script.
But I want to run  the python script in a php file. Can anyone help me with it?
I want to know the ways that don't use the functions like exec() or shell_exec() or so...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a Python script from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php).  http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 1):

Running a Python script is very similar to running a binary. There are many options, the simplest one:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

```
`python path/to/script`;
```

Few there are other function to look at:

- exec
- shell_exec
- system
- passthru

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php

Comment: if all those functions are disabled for security reasons, then how can I do?

Comment: If those function are disabled, You cannot. I am afraid. Someone has configured PHP to not execute external programs or scripts.