# Run python script from html page Flask

Tags: python, flask

How do we execute or run python code after the submit button is pressed the html form that I created in index.html.

The following is the index.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="nopol">
        <input id="print_nopol" type="submit">
      </form>

     <?php
        system("python /home/pi/python-epson-printer/epson_printer/testpage.py");
     ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

and below is a python flask application script with the name app.py :

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, Response, redirect, url_for
from os import listdir
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    input_nopol = request.form['nopol']
    if request.method == 'POST':
       with open('nopol.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(input_nopol))
    return render_template('index.html', nopol=input_nopol)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(host='192.168.1.2', port=8080, debug=True)
```

This python code has a function to insert data into a .txt file and here is the python script path:

```
/home/pi/server_print/print.py
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why dont use REST Api model?

Comment: I want a simple code. Because the function is only to run python script.

Comment: is this used in production or only locally?

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php

Comment: instead of using PHP use ajax to call python function