# Running a python script from php and writing data values in mysql database

Tags: php, python, mysql

I am trying to run a python script from php and access a mysql database 
it works completely when i use

```
$python sample.py
```

but on using

```
$output=shell_exec('python sample.py');

echo $output
```

it doesn't execute the python script though .php has the permissions

```
$sudo chmod +x sample.php

$sudo chown www-data:www-data sample.php

$sudo chmod u+x sample.php
```

Comment: Does it give you any output? Like an error message perhaps?

Comment: see normal output in a file first if you are running on linux
$output=shell_exec('python sample.py > file.txt');
and the see what written on file.txt

Comment: in database it does not give any output. I ahve tried adding simple print statements also but they are also not getting executed.It is returning an empty text file file.txt

Comment: Can you have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php and see if that helps.

Comment: thanks but i have already tried all the commands there it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can try this non-direct method

`shell_exec('python sample.py > output.txt');
$output = file_get_contents('output.txt','r');
echo $output;
shell_exec('rm output.txt');`

Answer (score 0):

Enter exact syntax as you put it on terminal

`$output=shell_exec('python sample.py');`
or

`$output=shell_exec('python -i sample.py');`

or make it executable`chmod +x sample.py`

then
`$output=shell_exec('./sample.py');`