# running a python program after pressing button in php

Tags: php, python, html

I have made big data project in python and the frontend in HTML and PHP. I am taking an input from the frontend and saving it to csv file using php when the submit button is pressed. Now I want that when I take input it is read by python from csv file and run data mining algorithm which I coded in python. How can a python program be executed when a submit button is pressed in the frontend made through php and html.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php

Comment: i am unable to do it

Comment: my program is written in spyder