# How to run Python Script on different Server from PHP webpage?

Tags: php, python

I have a hosting server which hosts my PHP Website and I have another server (Windows Server) which has Python App. I need to launch a Python App from my PHP Website when a user clicks the button on my website. I also need to get return data and display it on the website. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Take from [Running a Python script from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php)

```
<?php 

$command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/custom/test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;

?>
```