# Executing python scripts via PHP

Tags: php, python

I am trying to execute a python script via PHP. For some reason it doesn't execute. I have included the first line on my python code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Here is my PHP code that is executing this code (this is in index.php. test.py is in the same folder as this.):

```
if(isset($_GET["on"])){
    $command = escapeshellcmd("python test.py");
    shell_exec($command);
    echo "success";
}
```

But when I click the button to execute the script, I get "success" but the script doesn't execute. Any ideas why?

Comment: What does it output when you use `echo shell_exec($command);`?

Comment: Nevermind, I just fixed this problem by accessing sudo visudo and adding this: www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Comment: you should **NOT** do that. if any attacker ever gets your php-scripts to execute arbitrary commands, they're executed "only" as www-data. but with your workaround, attackers can run commands as root - at which point the server is basically theirs. if you have to grant your webserver sudo-right, do it with a *very strict* whitelist of commands.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux, your script might not have correct privileges: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#37971

try:

```
chmod +x test.py
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19736494/6337641