# Running Python scripts using PHP on a Windows Server

Tags: php, python, batch-file, windows-server-2012-r2

SOLUTION: My Python file was crashing with no output, I was able to diagnose this with a try/except that printed the error message. Oops!

I have a Windows 2012R2 IIS server set up to display websites that exist within a GitHub repo. After pulling the pages down from the repo I need to process them using a Python script, up to this point this happens twice a day as a scheduled task. The users would like to be able to run the batch file that updates/processes the files by clicking a button in the admin panel of the site. To do this I have created a PHP page that is supposed to execute the same batch file that the scheduled task uses. The problem I am running into is when the batch runs the git commands are executed just fine, but the Python script does not run.

I have already tried running the batch file using exec(), system(), and shell_exec(). I also tried running the batch file from a powershell script that runs the batch file. I'm guessing the PHP doesn't have the needed permissions to run Python files. Which is why I also tried passing Admin credentials to powershell through shell_exec. All of these have failed.

Here is watch the batch file looks like

```
cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot
git fetch --all
git reset --hard master
git pull https://username:password@github.com/user/repo_name
cd C:\inetpub
C:\Python37\python C:\inetpub\api_replace.py
```

And this is what I currently have in the PHP file.

```php
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["admin"]) || $_SESSION["admin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}

$shellout = shell_exec('powershell C:\inetpub\refresh_pages.bat server_name\Administrator password');
echo $shellout
?>
```

I have also tried running the Python file directly through exec(), system(), and shell_exec().

The results of the git pull show up on the page, but none of the print statements from the Python file do. The necessary file processing also does not occur.

Comment: To run a Python script in PHP you can use shell_exec as can be see in one answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php

Comment: As I mentioned I have tried that (actually from the exact answer you linked). Also this is a Windows server.

Comment: If you have indeed found a solution to your issue, consider posting it as a self-answer below so that others may leverage it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: My Python file was crashing with no output, I was able to diagnose this with a try/except that printed the error message. Oops!