# is there any way to access python snippets in our php code?

Tags: python, php, ubuntu, cross-platform, code-snippets

I am working on PHP code and i need to use a part of code that i've **already written in Python**. The python code is saved as snippet. So is there any way that i can access that snippet in my PHP code?
P.S. i am also looking for a way to save those snippets on cloud (not in my local server so that my entire team can look at those snippets and add their own if required and also access the snippets functionality rather than importing entire snippet in their code). If you can tell some platforms for them as well it would be great help.

I am working on Ubuntu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a Python script from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php)

Comment: Try and keep your questions simple, your P.S. question is really a separate problem, which is more likely to be answered if you ask it as its own question.

Comment: so i will generalize the question in really simple words: I need to run my python code in PHP file. So is there any way to embed my python code file with PHP file?? (The file can be written in any language)