# Run python script from PHP file

Tags: php

I am trying to run a python file using PHP, but the file doesn't print Hi and I only print "Whatsup". The script is run when the user clicks a submit button. I am on OSX and all the file paths are correct. I did chmod +x hi.py as suggested in another post

hi.py

```
#set up classes
# figure out regex
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3


print("Hi")
```

signup.inc.php

```
else {
      $command=escapeshellcmd('/Users/name/Documents/CPSC_Courses/CPSC353/CoronaVirus/webScrap.py');
      $output = shell_exec($command);
      echo $output;
      echo "Whatsup";
      exit();
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a Python script from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php)

Comment: Unfortunately no. I did chmod +x myscript.py to the file and still nothing.

Comment: Just as a quick test, copy the python script to the same directory as your php script and see if that runs.

Comment: Just did. Same result. Then I switched the path in signup.inc.php to match the new file and nothing.

Comment: This command: `/usr/bin/python /Users/name/Documents/CPSC_Courses/CPSC353/CoronaVirus/webScrap.py` works from Terminal?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell which python to use + where it is like:

```
else {
      $command=escapeshellcmd('/usr/bin/python /Users/name/Documents/CPSC_Courses/CPSC353/CoronaVirus/webScrap.py');
      $output = shell_exec($command);
      echo $output;
      echo "Whatsup";
      exit();
    }
```

OR for Python3:

```
else {
      $command=escapeshellcmd('/usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/name/Documents/CPSC_Courses/CPSC353/CoronaVirus/webScrap.py');
      $output = shell_exec($command);
      echo $output;
      echo "Whatsup";
      exit();
    }
```

Check where your Python is and add FULL path for it.

I would just use:

```
echo shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/name/Documents/CPSC_Courses/CPSC353/CoronaVirus/webScrap.py");
```

Comment: $command = escapeshellcmd('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 /Users/ name/Documents/CPSC_Courses/CPSC353/CoronaVirus/includes/webScrap.py');                              

Changed the command to show this but still get the same result. Used "which python3" to get path to python3

Comment: If thats where your Python is then it will work. Why you use escapeshellcmd its not dependent by user input?

Comment: That's just what the other stack overflow question answers suggested. What should I be using?

Comment: Is there another way to find my python? If I got through my files I have a folder called python 3.8 but there is no .exe file to path to.

Comment: did "which python" got /usr/bin/python. Tried it and same result

Comment: You see `Whatsup` only? Or is issue with your ELSE statement? I use it this way and it works fine.

Comment: Ya I only see "Whatsup". I have the command and echo $output before the echo "Whatsup". So in order to print "Whatsup" I have to have entered the Else statement right?

Comment: Switched to echo shell_exec(<python path> <file.py path>); however still no luck. I only see "Whatsup"... I just want it to say "Hi" :(

Comment: Yes, correct. From php file try: `echo shell_exec("/usr/bin/python -V");`

Comment: Just tried it. Still only see "Whatsup" I also tried with python3 filepath and same result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213136/discussion-between-cyborg-and-that-guy-808).