# how to run python script from php which generates a file

Tags: python, php, python-3.x

I'm trying to run python script from php using shell_exec() but it is not working. code is mentioned below

shell_exec() is working for other commands like checking version of python etc.

P.S - init.py is working normally when I run it through cmd.

**test.php**

```
<?php 
shell_exec("python C:/wamp64/www/projectx/vc/init.py test123");
?>
```

**init.py**

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import sys
image = Image.open('images/background.png')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
font = ImageFont.truetype('Times New Roman Gras 700.ttf', size = 100)
(x, y) = (150, 100)
color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
draw.text((x, y), sys.argv[1], fill = color, font = font)
image.save('images/image.png')
```

Comment: Consider to use absolute pathes (both for image and font). Consider to use logging, to see where / why the code fails.

Comment: specify the full python path. You can get your python path with `where python` on Windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a Python script from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php)

Comment: Yeah Thanks!! its working.