# Displaying raspberry pi core temperature on a site

Tags: python, php, file, web, raspberry-pi

So I'm wondering, I found a script online that outputs the temperature of the raspberry pi every 2 seconds:

```
import os
import time

def measure_temp():
        temp = os.popen("vcgencmd measure_temp").readline()
        return (temp.replace("temp=",""))

while True:
        print(measure_temp())
        time.sleep(1)
```

I've also created a server and site using the standard apache method. In /var/www/html I have a file called 'phptest.php' that will makeup the site and I have a python file called 'monitor-temp.py' which contains the above code for outputting the temp.

My question is, how do I successfully add the python code to the php file and hence display the temperature on the site?

Can I literally just type out the python code into the php file using nano phptest.php? Or do I the php file to somehow access the python file.

I see a lot of guides saying to add this to the php file to execute the python code:

```
<?php
    $command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/custom/test.py');
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;
?>
```

but that doesn't do anything for me. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Python script you provided is using `vcgencmd` CLI utility, nothing more. You can run it directly from PHP (no Python needed):

```php
<?php
// escape shell metacharacters
$command = \escapeshellcmd('vcgencmd measure_temp');

// execute vcgencmd CLI utility directly; write it's output to a variable
$output = \shell_exec($command);

// remove redundant prefix 'temp='
$output = \str_replace('temp=', '', $output);

echo $output;
```

If you still want to do it via Python script, you either need to specify Python interpreter:

```php
<?php
$command = \escapeshellcmd('python3 /path/to/script.py');
$output = \shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```

or [follow instructions from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19736494/7213838).

Comment: Wow thank you so much! You're an angel. I have no doubts that this is exactly the code I need, however on my site i get an error: VCIH initialisation fail". Searching for a fix online tells me I need to "add the correct video group to the user". I then run 'sudo usermod -aG video <username>' but it doesn't seem to fix it. Do you know anything about this? Thanks again

Comment: As Apache is running under the "www-data" user and group you need to to add the video group to this user: `sudo usermod -aG video www-data`. Apache restart might be required after that `sudo service apache2 restart`
@Varattican  Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just getting started and are looking for simplicity and something that just works, you may not be aware that PHP includes a [simple web server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) that you can run without needing to set up and configure Apache at all.

This script will get the Raspberry Pi temperature and display it. Save it as `server.php`:

```
<?php
   echo '<pre>';
   $output = system("/usr/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp");
   echo '</pre>';
?>
```

And you can run it as a web server from the Terminal without Apache or anything else like this:

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 server.php
```

Find it in your web browser at:

```
http://RASPI_IP_ADDRESS:8000
```