# executing a none php file from a php file showing error: word unexpected

Tags: python, php, exec

I am trying to use php exec() function to execute a python file. When i try something like this:

`echo exec("python app.py")`;

It works but if i omit the `python` string and keep it like this:

`echo exec("app.py")`,

it gives this error: `Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")"` which also shows up even if i change from python to another language other than php like JavaScript

app.py only contains one code line: `print("Hello World")`.

What am i doing wrong please as this is my first time using the `exec()` function.

Comment: Is the file executable? Maybe read through this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19736494/231316

Comment: yea the file is executable. It works if only i add the file type parameter. I guess that's how it's meant to work

Answer (score 0):

1. `app.py` should include a [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) so it will look like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
print("Hello World")
```

2. `echo exec("./app.py")`

Hope this works and helps!

~ PanTrakX

Comment: thanks but the error is still there after adding the Shebang and modifying my php as 2