# PHP - Is it possible to pass a variable from php to Python?

Tags: python, php, wordpress, plugins

I am working on a song playing project and got stuck. Is there a way of passing a variable from php to python. I am working on a wordpress website and in some parts I used Python code and used php plugin to get the code working on that website. But here is the thing because I constantly need to copy the script and make new versions of it because I have to specify the path to the song and then insert the plugin into the website. So I was wondering if there is a way in which I could add this path to the python script trough php (meaning that I vould insert the path in php code instead of python)?

This is my plugin:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/* Plugin Name: Python embedded */

add_shortcode( 'python', 'embed_python' );

function embed_python( $attributes )
{
    $data = shortcode_atts(
        [
            'file' => 'hello.py'
        ],
        $attributes
    );

    $handle = popen( __DIR__ . '/' . $data['file'], 'r' );
    $read = '';

    while ( ! feof( $handle ) )
    {
        $read .= fread( $handle, 2096 );
    }

    pclose( $handle );

    return $read;
}
```

Is this even possible? Any ideas?

Comment: How do you run the Python script ?

Comment: Just added the plugin script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be actually using python code inside php scripts since it can really mess up with your compiler.
You should CALL THE EXECUTION of the script by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php)

Then you could provide arguments to execute python scripts :

```
python3 hello.py arg1 arg2
```

And then from python script you would get arguments like this:

```
import sys
#sys.argv[0] is the name of the file ( hello.py )
arg1 = sys.argv[1]
arg2 = sys.argv[2]
...
```

Edit : its a follow up from  Ken Lee's comment

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot, but i don't understand how do these arguments work. Is there a yt video about it

Comment: There is a youtube vid for everything bro :)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G10Q8vKvQyc

Answer (score 2):

In my understanding after you have installed the WP plugin then you can execute the python code in your WP by the following shortcode:

```
[python file="hello.py"]
```

Please either (1) save the variable to a TXT file by PHP and then in your hello.py read the TXT file to get the data value ;

or (2) save the variable to Mysql database table by PHP and then in your hello.py read the Mysql database table. [reference link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_select.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your information, but is it possible to just insert python code in php?

Comment: For direct execution of python thru php, you may use shell exec [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php). Python is able to read the parameter as arguments [reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm)