# Run Python from PHP code not executed problem

Tags: python, php, shell-exec

I have php code and python code and i use visual studio code as code editor, i use xampp apache for personal server. The code is below :

Html run button

```
<form action="" method="post">
          <div class="card-header py-3 mb-30 mt-20 pb-20 pt-20">
                <div class="center">
                <input type="submit" name="runpython" value="Run" class="btn btn-primary">
          </div>
</div>
</form>
```

This is the run python by php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['runpython'])){
   $output = shell_exec('python3 /xampp/htdocs/Klasifikasi_KNN/admin test.py');
   echo $output;
   echo shell_exec('/xampp/htdocs/Klasifikasi_KNN/admin test.py');
   $output = shell_exec('python3 /xampp/htdocs/Klasifikasi_KNN/admin test.py');
   echo $output;
   echo shell_exec('xampp/htdocs/Klasifikasi_KNN/admin test.py');
   echo shell_exec('/xampp/htdocs/Klasifikasi_KNN/admin test.py');
   echo shell_exec('/xampp/htdocs/Klasifikasi_KNN/admin/test.py');
   echo shell_exec('xampp/htdocs/Klasifikasi_KNN/admin/test.py');
   echo shell_exec('python3 xampp/htdocs/Klasifikasi_KNN/admin/test.py');
   echo shell_exec('python3 /xampp/htdocs/Klasifikasi_KNN/admin/test.py');
}
?>
```

This is the test.py

```
#! C:/Users/Jessen PC/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe
print("Hello World")
```

What ive tried :

1. check if shell_exect is exist

```
    if(function_exists('exec')) {
        echo "exec is enabled";
    }
    if(function_exists('shell_exec')) {
        echo "shell_exec is enabled";
    }
```

2. Prove shell exect is working

```
if (exec('echo TEST') == 'TEST')
{
    echo 'exec works!';
}
```

output :
exec works! exec is enabled shell_exec is enabled"

3. Added handler script in httpd.conf in config xampp

```
AddHandler cgi-script .py
ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict
```

4. If i use D drive like this

```
$output = shell_exec('D:/xampp/htdocs/Klasifikasi_KNN/admin/test.py');
echo $output;
```

This open like image below
[image: output]
What im aiming is the code is debug by python and display the output in website.

Is there something missing needs to be done to execute python files from php?

Comment: You might want to prove that `shell_exec` is working first?  Verify that you can run the basic example as per [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php).

Comment: Although your button has `name="runpython"`, that does not cause the POST request to have a variable named `runpython`.  So `if(isset($_POST['runpython']))` is false and your Python won't run.  Add something to your form like `<input type="hidden" name="runpython" value="foo"/>`

Comment: @metatoaster yes i have prove it and edited the questions thankyou, the shell exect is working fine.

Comment: @BareNakedCoder I don't see how `if(isset($_POST['runpython']))` could be false when the form has been submitted. There _is_ an element with `name="runpython"`. Using a hidden input wouldn't make a difference

Comment: Have you tried using the complete path to `python` _and_ the complete path to your script?

Comment: @brombeer  is this what you mean by complete path to python? #! C:/Users/Jessen PC/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe and this is complete path to the script? $output = shell_exec('D:/xampp/htdocs/Klasifikasi_KNN/admin/test.py');
echo $output;

Comment: Something like `$output = shell_exec('C:/Users/Jessen PC/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe D:/xampp/htdocs/Klasifikasi_KNN/admin/test.py'); echo $output;`

Comment: @brombeer Its only open the file on vscode not executing the script and display the output in website

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250996/discussion-between-jessen-jie-and-brombeer).

Comment: @brombeer Thankyou i try using anaconda python installation path like this echo shell_exec('D:\Anaconda\python.exe D:/xampp/htdocs/Klasifikasi_KNN/admin/test.py'); now it works.

Comment: Nice, grats. Glad it works! ;)