# Python script is non working when called from PHP

Tags: php, python-3.x, ubuntu

I've seen several posts about this subject, none worked.
exec() and similar shell commands works fine only for Linux commands (eg. ls) not for Python scripts
Initially I thought there was something wrong with my test.py, but even a simple print() doesn't work. Here's what happen:

OS: Ubuntu 22.04

PHP: 8.0

Python: 3.10

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
Print("Hello Word")  # that simple
```

from terminal, it works:

```
> python3 test.py   // Hello World
```

myscript1.php | doesn't work

```
$command = escapeshellcmd("/mysite.com/path/python3 test.py ");
$out = shell_exec($command);
file_put_contents( $txt_path.'test.txt', $out);   // test.txt is empty
```

myscript2.php | it works, but it's not a python script

```
$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
$t1= "<pre>$output</pre>";
file_put_contents( $txt_path.'out.txt', $t1 ) ;  // out.txt contains the list of files
```

I've granted permissions to all users, and test.py is executable.
Tried all shell functions: passthru(), shell_exec(), exec()
php.ini -> disabled_functions: none of them is listed, and I've removed pcntl_exec()

```
> sudo chmod a+rwx /mysite.com/path/ 
> chmod +x  test.py
```

Please help
Many thanks

[Running a Python script from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php)

Comment: Maybe `python3 /mysite.com/path/test.py`? python3 can be called from every directory. Its not very clear where your files are located.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out how to fix this issue.

*shell_exec()* commands doesn’t work unless I shape the string as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
$command ="/usr/bin/python3   /my/path/test.py ";   // this is !crucial
$out = shell_exec($command);   
file_put_contents( '/my/path/test.txt', $out);   // test.txt is now working
```

Still I don’t know why the python’s path has to be declared separately that way when from terminal the following works just fine:

*> python3 /my/path/test.py*

Comment: But it may be sh and not bash and is a different environment.