# Unable to execute python script from php on web when mysql module is included in python

Tags: python, php, mysql

This is my php code :

```
$output = shell_exec("python3 test.py");

echo $output;
```

This is my python code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests
import sys


print("Hello from Python")
```

it show text `Hello from Python` when accessed from browser and also terminal using `php test.php`

When I change my python code to include `import mysql.connector`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests
import mysql.connector
import sys


print("Hello from Python")
```

it show text `Hello from Python` when accessed from terminal using `php test.php` but not showing anything when accessed using my browser, why?

Comment: What exactly do you mean "accessed using my browser"?  How is that done?  What exact address in the browser?

Comment: localhost/test.php

Comment: as far as I recall additional python modules are installed per user (though I may be wrong). The terminal user is not the same as the user for the PHP process that runs in response to web requests

Comment: @apokryfos anyway to fix this?

Comment: Possibly `sudo -u www-data pip install mysql`

Comment: Suggest reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19736494/2067753 especially "*you need to make sure that the web user has rights to whatever files or directories that you are trying to use in the shell_exec command. Other wise, it won't appear to be doing anything.*" btw: you probably need to identify the o/s (and version) you are using